# Xamarin + sqlite-net dependency errors

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, sqlite-net

So I'm trying to setup a cross-platform app with Xamarin for iOS + Android.

I included sqlite-net package in the PCL, and now I have dependency problems for either Windows 8, or Silverlight (that I both don't need to support).

If I chose a profile like profile24 which supports silverlight, I get the following error :

> Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Stopwatch' does not exist in
>   the namespace `System.Diagnostics'. Are you missing an assembly
>   reference? (CS0234)

On the other hand, if I chose a profile like profile49 with windows 8 and windows phone 8, I get errors such as :

> Error CS0117: 'System.Threading.Thread' does not contain a definition
>   for `VolatileWrite' (CS0117)

Or with profile111 (windows 8 + windows phone 8.1) :

> Error CS0103: The name `Thread' does not exist in the current context
>   (CS0103)

Thing is, I don't need to support those platforms. But there is no profile including just Xamarin.iOS + Xamarin.Android. I am forced to support those platforms that bring trouble.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok if anyone got the same problem : even though both are available in the package gallery, for use in a PCL, you have to include the `SQLite.NET PCL` package, and not the one named `sqlite-net`.

Update: also, if you want to use the async methods, you have to include the distinct package SQLite.Net.Async-PCL.